# Can't get Firebase update() to work with provided object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Ok, so after a lot of trial and error I have to try asking here. 
I'm trying to update a Firebase entry and my code look like this,

This is from my service.js:

```
//This dosn't work
var updateItem = function (item, id) {
    var ref  = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI + '/lessons/' + id);
    ref.$update(item);
}

//This works (items is a ref to new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI + '/lessons/');
var addItem = function (item) {
    items.$add(item);
}
```

And this is from my controller:

```
$scope.updateLesson = function (item) {
    LessonsService.updateLesson(item, id);
}
```

The error I'm getting is this:

Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains an invalid key ($id).  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

The object I'm passing in looks like this:

```
Object {
    $id: "-JLIUvVMLqoCVgHaed9f", 
    $bind: function, $add: function, $save: function,     $set: function…}
    $add: function (item) {
    $auth: function (token) {
    $bind: function (scope, name, defaultFn) {
    $child: function (key) {
    $getIndex: function () {
    $getRef: function () {
    $id: "-JLIUvVMLqoCVgHaed9f"
    $off: function (type, callback) {
    $on: function (type, callback) {
    $remove: function (key) {
    $save: function (key) {
    $set: function (newValue) {
    $transaction: function (updateFn, applyLocally) {
    $update: function (newValue) {
    createDate: "2014-04-24T11:29:42.692Z"
    desc: "test"
    somemorevalues: "here"
}
```

I have tried to do a JSON.stringify on the object and got a nice looking result looking like this:

```
 {
  createDate: "2014-04-24T11:29:42.692Z",
  desc: "test",
  somemorevalues: "here"
 }
```

But it wont accept it when I'm passing that in thru a variable. (Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.) If I pass it in directly as a string it works thou (?!!!). It's the exact same information in the variable.. What the hell am I missing?! As of now I'm building my own object like this:

```
 var newItem = {
     title: item.title,
     desc: item.desc,
     ingress: item.ingress,
     workarea: item.workarea,
     years: {val: item.years.val},
 }
```

and passing that along to firebase, which works but is not ideal because its "static".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use angularFire according to [the API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html). Read the [Angular+Firebase Overview](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/) for a good primer.

In essence, instead of passing angularFire objects into a Firebase ref (which will not work since keys may not have a $ in the name) and calling update/set yourself, simply use the `$set`/`$update` methods already available on the $firebase object:

```
var ref = $firebase(URL);
ref[id].desc = 'foo';
ref.$save(id).then(onComplete);
```

Comment: Well, I cant get it to work. The $add function works just fine with the passed in item. But not the $update.

Comment: You haven't called $update anywhere in your example, so it will be hard to offer much assistance.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I pasted the wrong code. I was tinkering trying to get it to work. It shouldnt be .set() it should be .update().

Comment: The problem is that you are passing in the $firebase object and trying to use it in a ref. Just call $update an "item" that you are passing in, instead of creating a Firebase reference. Look at [examples in the API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html) for more details.

Comment: Ah, stupid me. I'm sorry. I just took for granted you needed the ref. it works just fine using $scope.item.$update(item) just as the docs says. Sorry again for reading the docs to poorly.

Comment: I'm having this issue too and not very clear how this is working. Would anyone care to explain this solution better?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its just a typo but you've got a comma after the years value (removed it below).

```
var newItem = {
    title: item.title,
    desc: item.desc,
    ingress: item.ingress,
    workarea: item.workarea,
    years: {val: item.years.val}
 }
```

As it thinks that its trying to pass an empty key after years, therefor giving the error.